# JavaScript - after I reset my counter and assign the number it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

So I made a counter. When you press "begin" the "word" appears and then you can start pressing the red square and after each press the number increases by 1. When number is bigger than 5 "reset" appears. After you press "reset" the counter should reset and work normally. **But for some reason, even thought I assign the number value to 0, after I press "reset" and then press "begin" and then start pressing the red square the number increases not by 1 but by 2.** If you don't understand my problem I'll try to explain it in more detail.

```js
var square = document.getElementById("square");
var numb = document.getElementById("number");
var num = 0;
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
var word = document.getElementById("word");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");

begin.addEventListener("click", function() {
  word.style.display = "block";
  if (word.style.display == "block") {
    square.addEventListener("click", function() {
     if (num > 5) {
        word.style.display = "none";
        reset.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        num = num + 1;
        numb.innerHTML = num;
      }
    })
  }
})

reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
  num = 0;
  numb.innerHTML = num;
  reset.style.display = "none";
})
```

```css
#square{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#number{
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#begin{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#word{
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}

#reset{
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
<div id="number">0</div>
<div id="begin">begin</div>
<div id="word">word</div>
<div id="reset">reset</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because you add an extra click event to the red square event everytime you click on the begin button. If you press begin 5 times and then click on the red square ones, you will see it will instantly jump to 5.

You can fix this by moving the square click event outside of the button click. Now you can add a boolean flag to check if you are allowed to click. (`canClick` in my example)

```js
var square = document.getElementById("square");
var numb = document.getElementById("number");
var num = 0;
var begin = document.getElementById("begin");
var word = document.getElementById("word");
var reset = document.getElementById("reset");
var canClick = false

begin.addEventListener("click", function() {
  word.style.display = "block";
  if (word.style.display == "block") {
    canClick = true;
  }
})

square.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(canClick) {
    if (num > 5) {
      word.style.display = "none";
      reset.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      num = num + 1;
      numb.innerHTML = num;
    }
  }
})

reset.addEventListener("click", function(){
  num = 0;
  numb.innerHTML = num;
  reset.style.display = "none";
  canClick = false;
})
```

```css
#square{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

#number{
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#begin{
  position: absolute;
  top: 300px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

#word{
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}

#reset{
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="square"></div>
<div id="number">0</div>
<div id="begin">begin</div>
<div id="word">word</div>
<div id="reset">reset</div>
```